# Skip first-child selector's style for specific element

Tags: css, css-selectors

Lets say we have generic css class for table to use on all places in our application. Lets consider also this style has first-child selector.

```
tr td:first-child { ... }
```

I would like to use this class for an specific table but skip all first-child styles.

Since this is generic style class for tables i cant remove from it and also dont want to handle this with inline styling.

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit unclear what you mean. So say for example `tr td:first-child { ... }` has a yellow background, do you want to [1] apply a class to a specific table where it does not have a yellow background, ie.. override the default? Or [2] have a class which gives all cells a red background, but the first cell is still yellow?

Comment: scenario 1 is the one i asked actually. Still i want to use that class for that spesific table but just don't apply yellow  background as it is on first-child selector. The other tables  which use that class, should have background yellow as normal behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

You could be more specific for that particular `table`, assuming it has a class or an id you can use:

```css
tr td:first-child {
  color: red;
}
.test tr td:first-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First td</td>
    <td>Second td</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="test">
  <tr>
    <td>First td</td>
    <td>Second td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Excuse the limited markup, but you get the point. Because the `.test tr td:first-child {}` class is more specific than the generic style, it overrides it, but only for the `table` with the class `test`.

More info on specifity: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: i see what you mean with creating more spesific class for that table but what if i dont want to write all styles again and just removing first-child selector?

Comment: @kurt_vonnegut There's no easy way of doing that since the styles under the generic `td:first-child` will pick up on all first `td`'s unless overriden further down the line - which is what I've demonstrated in my answer...